# Multiple json_object_agg functions in subquery return syntax error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE service (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    image VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE service_description (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    service_id INTEGER,
    language_id INTEGER,
    title VARCHAR,
    subtitle VARCHAR,
    col_left TEXT,
    col_right TEXT
);
```

I'm trying to retrieve the last 4 columns in the second table as objects with language_id as key.

The following query works (ommited col_left/right to save space)

```
SELECT
 s.*,
 (
   SELECT
     json_object_agg(language_id, title) AS title
   FROM
     service_description sd
 ),
 (
   SELECT
     json_object_agg(language_id, subtitle) AS subtitle
   FROM
     service_description sd
 )

FROM
    service s
```

Though when I do

```
SELECT
 s.*,
 (
   SELECT
     json_object_agg(language_id, title) AS title,
     json_object_agg(language_id, subtitle) AS subtitle
   FROM
     service_description sd
 )

FROM
    service s
```

I get err code 42601 - syntax error. What's wrong?

Comment: is this working `SELECT
     json_object_agg(language_id, title) AS title,
     json_object_agg(language_id, subtitle) AS subtitle
   FROM
     service_description sd`

Comment: Am not soo sure about Postgres generally we cannot select more than one column inside `sub-query` may be that could be reason. Try cross joining thee `sub-query` with the `service` table

Comment: Cross joining didn't help :/

Comment: So did you ran the query i commented. Did it execute without errors?

Comment: Just did now and it works. So I assume it's because of the subquery?

Comment: Try this `SELECT * 
FROM   service s 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Json_object_agg(language_id, title)    AS title, 
                          Json_object_agg(language_id, subtitle) AS subtitle 
                   FROM   service_description sd) B `

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot, you're the man. Answer the question so I can give you dem points?

Comment: The reason for the error is that in a select list you can use a _**scalar**_ select only, i.e. a query that returns a single value. Your query returned two columns, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your query is you are selecting more than one column inside the `sub-query`. Try  something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   service s 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Json_object_agg(language_id, title)    AS title, 
                          Json_object_agg(language_id, subtitle) AS subtitle 
                   FROM   service_description sd) B
```